# Child element doesn't seem to be a child element

Tags: javascript, html, css, parent-child

I've got a div for the drop down shadow inside the container but it doesn't seem to be the child of the container. My website: http://ps4news.eu.pn/homepage.html (It's for school). I'm gonna leave it shrinked so you can maybe tell what's wrong. I removed the height for the container so it would be as long as needed but when I do the same for the drop down shadow the container seems to shrink to the maximum size of the drop down shadow div. But the drop down shadow div is the child of the container element and while all the other divs inside the container don't effect the container only this one does. So what do I need to do to make it as long as the contianer?

Edit:
The drop down shadow actually is only 11 pixels long (I mean the image). But it seems to stop where the header stops.

If you mean this okay:

```
body { 
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px
}

#Container {
z-index:999999;
width: 1350px;
background-color:#CCC;
position:relative;
}

#DropDownShadow {
width: 1015px;
z-index:-9999;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
background-image: url(../images/bgdropshadow.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-y;
}

#Wrapper {
width: 975px;
height: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

#ContentHolder {
width:975px;
background:#0F0;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

#Header {
height: 125px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
background-color: #000;
width: 975px;
}

#Social-Networks {
height:36px;
width:164px;
margin-right:230px;
margin-top:80px;
float:right;
}

#Social-Networks img {
opacity:1;  
}

#Social-Networks img:hover {
opacity:0.9;
}

#ContentHolder1 {
width:650px;
height:925px;
margin-left:42px;
margin-right:auto;
margin-top:-10px;
background-color:transparent;
color: #8B8B8B;
}

#Side-Content {
width:250px;
height:600px;
float:right;
background-color:transparent;
}

#Content1 {
width: 725px;
height:1235px;
color: #9B9B9B;
margin-top:-18px;
margin-left:5px;
background-color: #03C;
border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 0px;
text-align: center;
font-family: "Open Sans";
}

hr {
height: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: black;
border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
border-radius: 4px;
}

#Copyright {
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
height: 25px;
width: 975px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
background-color: #0000d3;
text-align:left;
font-family:"Open Sans";
overflow:hidden;
}

<div id="Container">
  <div id="DropDownShadow">
    <div id="Wrapper">
      <div id="Header"> <img src="images/Header.png" width="400" height="95" 
  style=
  "position: absolute; 
  left: 189px;
  top:10px;">
        <div id="Social-Networks"><a href="http://www.playstation.com" title="Officiële Playstation-Website" target="_blank"><img id="Playstation" src="images/icons/Playstation-logo.png" width="36" height="36"></a><a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/PlayStation" title="Officiële Playstation Youtube Kanaal" target="_blank"><img src="images/icons/1387937374_Youtube.png" width="36" height="36" style="margin-left:5px;"></a><a href="https://twitter.com/PlayStation" title="Officiële Playstation Twitter" target="_blank"><img src="images/icons/1387937314_Twitter.png" width="36" height="36"
          style="margin-left:5px;"></a><a href="https://www.facebook.com/PlayStation" title="Officiële Playstation Facebook" target="_blank"><img src="images/icons/1387947454_Facebook.png" width="36" height="36" style="margin-left:5px;"></a></div>
      </div>
      <div id="ContentHolder">
        <div id='cssmenu'>
          <ul>
            <li class='active'><a href='homepage.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
            <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Artikelen</span></a>
              <ul>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Nederlands</span></a> </li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Engels</span></a> </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href='gallery.html'><span>Galerij</span></a></li>
            <li style="float:right" class='last'><a href='#'><span>Over</span></a></li>
            <li style="float:right" class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
          </ul>
          <div id="Side-Content"> 
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://output78.rssinclude.com/output?type=js&amp;id=815822&amp;hash=b0095ae8bebb910e5dc0f397a646173e"></script>
          </div>
          <div id="ContentHolder1">
            <h1>Gallerij</h1>
            <div id="Gallery">
              <header>Welcome to my Gallery</header>
              <section>
                <li><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/gallery/img/larg/image-01.jpg" title="Istanbul"><img src="images/gallery/img/thumbnails/image-01.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="Istanbul"></a></li>
                <li><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/gallery/img/larg/image-02.jpg" title="Istanbul"><img src="images/gallery/img/thumbnails/image-02.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="Istanbul"></a></li>
                <li><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/gallery/img/larg/image-03.jpg" title="Istanbul"><img src="images/gallery/img/thumbnails/image-03.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="Istanbul"></a></li>
                <li><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/gallery/img/larg/image-04.jpg" title="Istanbul"><img src="images/gallery/img/thumbnails/image-04.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="Istanbul"></a></li>
                <li><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/gallery/img/larg/image-05.jpg" title="Istanbul"><img src="images/gallery/img/thumbnails/image-05.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="Istanbul"></a></li>
                <li><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/gallery/img/larg/image-06.jpg" title="Istanbul"><img src="images/gallery/img/thumbnails/image-06.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="Istanbul"></a></li>
                <li><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/gallery/img/larg/image-07.jpg" title="Istanbul"><img src="images/gallery/img/thumbnails/image-07.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="Istanbul"></a></li>
                <li><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/gallery/img/larg/image-08.jpg" title="Istanbul"><img src="images/gallery/img/thumbnails/image-08.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="Istanbul"></a></li>
                <li><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/gallery/img/larg/image-01.jpg" title="Istanbul"><img src="images/gallery/img/thumbnails/image-01.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="Istanbul"></a></li>
                <li><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/gallery/img/larg/image-01.jpg" title="Istanbul"><img src="images/gallery/img/thumbnails/image-01.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="Istanbul"></a></li>
                <li><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/gallery/img/larg/image-01.jpg" title="Istanbul"><img src="images/gallery/img/thumbnails/image-01.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="Istanbul"></a></li>
                <li><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/gallery/img/larg/image-01.jpg" title="Istanbul"><img src="images/gallery/img/thumbnails/image-01.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="Istanbul"></a></li>
                <li><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/gallery/img/larg/image-01.jpg" title="Istanbul"><img src="images/gallery/img/thumbnails/image-01.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="Istanbul"></a></li>
                <li><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/gallery/img/larg/image-01.jpg" title="Istanbul"><img src="images/gallery/img/thumbnails/image-01.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="Istanbul"></a></li>
                <li><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/gallery/img/larg/image-01.jpg" title="Istanbul"><img src="images/gallery/img/thumbnails/image-01.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="Istanbul"></a></li>
              </section>
              <footer>All Rights Reserved</footer>
              <!-- Add jQuery library --> 
              <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script> 
              <!-- Add fancyBox -->
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="images/gallery/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
              <script type="text/javascript" src="images/gallery/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="images/gallery/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
              <script type="text/javascript" src="images/gallery/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script> 
              <script type="text/javascript">
  $(".fancybox")
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
        padding : 0,
    prevEffect  : 'none',
    nextEffect  : 'none',
    helpers  : {
      title  : {
        type: 'outside'
      },
      thumbs  : {
        width  : 50,
        height  : 50
      }
    }
    });
</script> 
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Copyright">&copy;Copyright Mounteder Abdulrazag, Tom Borghouts</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe post the relevant code so it'll be easier for others to debug and help.

Comment: Please post the container/child HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding `overflow: hidden;` to the container so that the size wouldn't change.